# Why do some files appear as partial gibberish when opened in a text editor?

Tags: text, encoding, character-encoding

I often come across the situation where I would like to read a file's original content in a human-readable way. When opening this kind of file in a text editor, why is it that it is usually gibberish *with some complete and comprehensible text* ? I would think that if the file is converted to something other than it's original written format, that there would be *no comprehensible text* remaining, yet I often find it is somewhere in between.

For example, I know that if I open a binary in a text format, there will be nothing comprehensible left that isn't purely accidental.

[Example screencapture of partial gibberish text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyB7S.png)

Why is there complete text in here mixed with gibberish? Does that mean if I open the file with some sort of different encoding (I don't know what's possible), the file will come through as fully readable text? I would understand if it were all-or-nothing (either gibberish-non-readable OR human language) but I don't understand the in-between.

Please provide educational responses, rather than *"because that's the way it is"* type answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are formatting characters; there is no standard use and vary by the format of the file in question.  You can still extract the text as needed with a fair knowledge of grep and regex, but it won't be fun.  The best bet is to open the file with the software that can read it properly, as a text editor like gedit or Notepad++ will read the raw data and display that.  Adobe's pdf format has text embedded, for instance, and all that gibberish is instructions for the Reader software for displaying it correctly on the screen while still allowing for relatively straightforward text extraction when required.

Editors have no real way to interpret the special formatting characters, and would need to be loaded with APIs for every conceivable program.  They would also need to be updated constantly, since the formatting changes regularly for a variety of reasons.  Many times, it is just to keep the files from being backward compatible with their own or other products, forcing an upgrade path.  Microsoft is rather famous for that, but they are by far not the only company to do so.